# RestTemplate executed in parallelstream

Tags: java, spring

Lets say I have collections of objects, then per each object i want to execute

```
RestTemplate.getForObject()
```

So i'd like to do for example:

```
List objects = new LinkedList<>();
objects.parallelstream.map(object -> makeApiCall(object)).collect(toList);
```

MakeApiCall is just a http get to foregin service. Is is executex async or the parellelstream gives no edge here?